# ASP.NET inline code in a server control

Tags: asp.net

Ok, we had a problem come up today at work. It is a strange one that I never would have even thought to try.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="Default.aspx?id=<%= ID %>" >
```

Ok, it is very ugly and I wouldn't have ever tried it myself. It came up in some code that was written years ago but had been working up until this weekend after a bunch of updates were installed on a client's web server where the code is hosted.

The actual result of this is the following html:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx?id=&lt;%= ID %>" id="form1">
```

The url ends up like this:

```
http://localhost:6735/Default.aspx?id=<%= ID %>
```

Which as you can see, demonstrates that the "<" symbol is being encoded before ASP.NET actually processes the page. It seems strange to me as I thought that even though it is not pretty by any means, it should work. I'm confused.

To make matters worse, the client insists that it is a bug in IE since it appears to work in Firefox. In fact, it is broken in Firefox as well, except for some reason Firefox treats it as a 0.

Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it easily? Everything I try to render within the server control ends up getting escaped.

**Edit**
Ok, I found a "fix"

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action='<%# String.Format("Default.aspx?id={0}", 5) %>' >
```

But that requires me to call DataBind which is adding more of a hack to the original hack. Guess if nobody thinks of anything else I'll have to go with that.

Comment: Wow! Are you sure there is no other way to fix this? Are you doing some kind of cross page post back? It is rare to see the "action" being specified for a webform app.

Comment: It is actually posting back to itself. Very strange indeed! It is all web forms with inline code "behind". I agree, I've actually never used the action attribute in web forms. Never had the need.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 3.5 added the "Action" property to the HtmlForm control.  Your previous code worked just fine because "action" was just a string, and the code nugget would emit the additional data for you.  Now that there is an Action property, you can't use a simple code emit nugget, since a server-side control expects a property to have a literal string value (same as any other server-side control property).

Your workaround of using the biding syntax is correct.  To make it work like it used to, you would have to remove the runat=server tag on your form, which would then prevent the ASPX parser from treating it as an HtmlForm control, and instead treat it as a literal (where your code emit nugget would be allowed to work).

Your other option, which may be much cleaner - is to simply set the Form's action property through code-behind in the page_load.  The reason the action property is set the way it is, was because in earlier versions of .NET Framework, there was no support for setting the Action property.

Comment: indeed, using `form1.Action = string.Format("default.aspx?id={0}", _id)` in your code behind is much cleaner. You did mention inline in your question title so maybe you have some reason to keep it inline though.

Answer (score 0):

your form needs a `runat=server`

Comment: As noted in the above example, it does have the runat="server"